# is there something like C sharp regions in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there something similar to Csharp's  `#region` in C++?

I googled but could not find something this convenient.

Comment: I don't use C#, but from googling #region it seems to be an IDE feature that the language supports (ignores) rather than a language feature. In C++ you can still collapse sections depending on your IDE, but it's not the language that enables it.

Comment: Most Ide are able to collapse/expand block such as `#if 1 #endif` as workaround.

Answer (score 4):

VC++ supports [`#pragma region` compiler-specific extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/region-endregion?view=vs-2019).

```
#pragma region name

#pragma endregion comment
```

Comment: @KansaiRobot That should be a pretty quick test to perform.

Answer (score -2):

> Is there something similar to Csharp's #region in C++?

Read the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) to find out

According to [this](https://www.dotnetperls.com/region), `#region` in C# is configuring your [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-code_editor)'s behavior, not the [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) (or run-time behavior) of your C# program. I could edit a C# source code with simple editors like `nano` or even `ed` for [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/) on Linux. (and then `#region` won't have its documented behavior). I could generate a C# file (or a C++ one) with my own [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or [Python](https://python.org/) script, then compile that file.

With tools like [geany](https://www.geany.org/), [clion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/), [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), or a well configured [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or [vim](https://vim.org/), you have similar -source code editing- behavior with C++.

Don't forget that a C++ [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) could `#include`  some machine generated header files. On most implementations, a translation unit is defined (notably by the behavior of the C++ preprocessor) as what your C++ compiler sees of your C++ code. 
Your `Makefile` or other build automation should care of that. You could use ad-hoc preprocessor directive.

Your vendor compiler (e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)) could provide useful extensions.

C++ provide `#line`  preprocessor directive, and you can have preprocessor macros which spans hundred of physical lines (read documention of [cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/)). Then combine them cleverly.

Comment: I'm speculating but I think the only reason this answer has gotten downvotes is because of the first sentense "_Read the C++11 standard n3337 to find out_". Other than that, it's good, isn't it?